# While migrating ionic 3 app to 4 getting an error in angular browser platform location

Tags: angular, ionic4

On running ionic serve I am getting an error saying non-abstract class browserplatformlocation does not implement inherited abstract member getState from class PlatformLocation

Export declare class BrowserPlatformLocation extends PlatforLocation.

In my app folder I am not using any location related code

Comment: Did you use the official doc from Ionic to migrate? https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration

Comment: Yes i am using the official doc

Comment: Did it work for you now?